# How to manipulate dates in OWL axioms

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, rdfs

I'm having trouble creating axioms that involve date properties (**xsd:dateTime**)

My ontology scope:

- It has a class **Fall**, where fall events with patients are
  individuals and it also has a data property **dateCreated** with
  range **xsd:dateTime**.
- There is another class **Fall From Last Semester**, which **Fall**
  individuals with **dateCreated** from the last 180 days are
  classified.

I tried with a fixed date (180 days before today) axiom:

[image]

It works, but I would like something like "**dateCreated** - **today** = 180", cause I won't have that fixed date in production.

Is there some way to do that with an axiom? Or I'll have to use some classes, separating day, month and year from the date?

Comment: that's not possible in OWL, there is no built-in function or predicate for `now` nor are you able to work with variables.[SWRL](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/#8.5) as rule language would allow variables and also some kind of maths, but for temporal stuff you would need some extension which then only works with their reasoning engine: https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLTemporalBuiltInsBasic#Current_Time

Comment: alternatively, you could have a look at some ways of working with the concept of time in OWL/SWRL: http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/system/files/swj855.pdf

Comment: thanks! I will take a look and study them